# Is there any microprocessor with only input pins or only output pins?

Tags: microprocessor

I want to know if there is any microprocessor without input? or without output?
I mean single way one.

Comment: I believe the Fairchild Write Only Memory chip has a special undocumented mode which allows it to be used as an inputs-only processor.  It will enter this mode if one shifts in all of the bits of *pi* or any other transcendental number, onto any data pin, at any desired data rate.  So if you can find one of those chips, you'll be all set.

Comment: @supercat LOL ;-)

Comment: There are write-only-memories which are almost as useful as a microprocessor with only inputs: http://www.national.com/rap/files/datasheet.pdf. Such devices are integrated in any UNIX computer. Thats were the data is directed to if you write to `/dev/null`

Comment: Yes.  I can't point you to data sheets, but consider specialized cryptography applications.  Also, depending on what you mean exactly, you could consider smart sensors as having only output, even though they accept environmental inputs.  Smart digital servo devices only accept input electronically, but again have a physical output.

Comment: @supercat - Get your manufacturs right!  The WOM (Write Only Memory) was a Signetics chip.  Signetics was later folded into Phillips/NXP, not Fairchild.  Bob Pease explains the story [here](http://www.national.com/rap/Story/WOMorigin.html), and the datasheet for the WOM is [here](http://www.national.com/rap/files/datasheet.pdf) (previously linked to by Curd).

Comment: thanks guys for your answers. This is a fairly a homework assignment of mine.

Comment: Check out the Signetics 25120 write-only memory.

Comment: I move to preserve this question for the WOM references.

Comment: AFAIR the RCA COSMAC CDP1801 had a single output only pin and no other on chip I/O per se. The indubitably   apocryphal story was that it had been developed for use in early A-bombs and that the output pin was for setting off the bomb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to imagine what a processor with only inputs would be good for. It would not be able to communicate with the outside world. Not to mention it would be really really really hard to debug any code you wrote for it.

A processor with only outputs would be impossible to program at all.

Answer (score 4):

Many microprocessors can be programmed as all inputs or all outputs, if that's really what you want.  In fact, many of them power up as all inputs until the program inside sets them otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIR the RCA COSMAC CDP1801 had a single output only pin and no other on chip I/O per se. The indubitably   apocryphal story was that it had been developed for use in early A-bombs and that the output pin was for setting off the bomb.

@Morten - input only pins could be used to trigger the HCF (Halt and Catch Fire) mode.
 eg opcode $DD on the MC6800

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any processors, but you there are 'mask ROMs'. These are chips where the data is directly encoded in the physical structure of the device. They are not programmed, just created as is. So for all intents they would be 'output only'.

The Nintendo Wii uses one (whether its a separate ROM chip or part of the CPU I don't actually know) to store the checksum of part of its bootloader. The idea being that over-writing the parts of the OS in flash storage would be futile since the checksum can't be changed or updated. (In practice they overlooked a step, and it got rooted anyways...)